# Batch Script to Execute script with python 3 if available else python 2

Tags: python, batch-file

Trying to create a batch script for windows that runs a program with python3 if available else python2.

I know the script can be executed with `$py -2 script.py`
and py3 with `$py -3 script.py`.

and if I run `py -0`, it returns all the python versions.

How do I build this script?

I do not want to check if the python directory is available or not, I'd prefer to check in a way that is python location agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piping directly `python.exe --version` to `find` or `findstr` is not working (with python 2.7).

Building dinamicaly and running a python script that return the version, will enable this piping !

The solution :

```
@echo off
set "$py=0"
call:construct

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('python #.py ^| findstr "2"') do set "$py=2"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('python #.py ^| findstr "3"') do set "$py=3"
del #.py
goto:%$py%

echo python is not installed or python's path Path is not in the %%$path%% env. var
exit/b

:2
echo running with PY 2

exit/b

:3
echo running with PY 3

exit/b

:construct
echo import sys; print('{0[0]}.{0[1]}'.format(sys.version_info^)^) >#.py
```

Comment: `python --version 2>&1 | findstr " 2.7"` ? Seems to work for 2 and 3. No temporary file needed.

Answer (score 7):

Not a full solution, but a method to detect which version of Python is installed:

You can check if Python 3 is installed by running `py -3 --version` and then checking the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable in the batch script.  If it is 0, then `py -3 --version` was successful, i.e. Python 3 is installed on the system.  If it is nonzero, then Python 3 is not installed.

Comment: I only have python 2.7 installed ! and when I run python -3 --version it return python 2.7 and the errorlevel still 0 !!!!

Comment: @SachaDee, `python.exe` is not `py.exe`. `python.exe` does not support `-0`, `-2` or `-3` arguments. The [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) `py.exe` does.

Comment: I have tried to run `py.exe` in my python 2.7, but it's apparently not present !

Comment: @SachaDee, You can get 3.7.0 launcher.msi for [x86](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/win32/) or [x64](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/amd64/). Use command `msiexec /i launcher.msi ALLUSERS=1` to install as an Admin. If you do not use the `ALLUSERS` property then it installs to the *UserProfile*. Tested with 2.7.15 in a Win 7 VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without temporary file

```
set PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION=0
for /f %%i in ('python -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info[0])"') do set PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION=%%i
```